# I need one word for adding and subtracting question

Tags: word-request

A kid asked me a question to say one word for adding and subtracting question. The question goes

> While adding and subtracting we put ____ in a correct place.

We have to use one word in the blank space.

I am confused if the answer is "operation", "sign", "operator" or something else.

Comment: *Sums* can be used for the problem itself - it is sufficiently generic to include differences, though I think it is a [plurale tantum](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plurale_tantum). For the plus or minus sign itself, *operator* is fine. In your sample sentence, use it with a determiner - e.g. *the operator*.

Comment: @Lawrence  I think it's worth making  "the operator" an answer.

Comment: Thanks @k1eran. I've expanded the comment slightly to form an answer.